# issues with yaml packages for firestorm

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, package

Do you know, what is the problem here and how to solve?

[kuechenrechner] flutter pub get
Running "flutter pub get" in kuechenrechner...
Because firebase_auth >=1.0.1 depends on firebase_auth_web ^1.0.1 which depends on http_parser ^4.0.0, firebase_auth >=1.0.1 requires http_parser ^4.0.0.

And because http >=0.11.3+17 <0.13.0-nullsafety.0 depends on http_parser >=0.0.1 <4.0.0, firebase_auth >=1.0.1 is incompatible with http >=0.11.3+17 <0.13.0-nullsafety.0.

Because vin_decoder 0.1.3 depends on http ^0.12.2 and vin_decoder >=0.1.2 <0.1.3 depends on http ^0.12.1, vin_decoder >=0.1.2 <=0.1.3 requires http ^0.12.1.

Thus, firebase_auth >=1.0.1 is incompatible with vin_decoder >=0.1.2 <=0.1.3.

And because no version of vin_decoder match >0.1.3 <0.2.0, firebase_auth >=1.0.1 is incompatible with vin_decoder ^0.1.2.

And because validators 2.0.1 depends on vin_decoder ^0.1.2 and no versions of validators match >2.0.1 <3.0.0, firebase_auth >=1.0.1 is incompatible with validators ^2.0.1.

And because flutter_form_builder 5.0.0 depends on validators ^2.0.1 and no versions of flutter_form_builder match >5.0.0 <6.0.0, firebase_auth >=1.0.1 is incompatible with flutter_form_builder ^5.0.0.

So, because kuechenrechner depends on both flutter_form_builder ^5.0.0 and firebase_auth ^1.0.1, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because kuechenrechner depends on both flutter_form_builder ^5.0.0 and firebase_auth ^1.0.1, version solving failed.)
exit code 1

Comment: you have to update packages to latest version

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your Firebase packages depend on many other packages. You need to update all dependencies and packages along with Firebase.